# Changing textContent of element

Tags: javascript

I'm making a form for registration and want to show error in another element if the input doesn't match a condition.

```
//input element
let field = document.getElementById("field").value.trim();
//div for showing error 
let field_error = document.getElementById("field_error").textContent;
if(field.length > 30){
field_error = "Input too long";
}
```

If I write code like this it doesn't do anything, but if I put like this:

```
let field_error = document.getElementById("field_error");
if(field.length > 30){
field_error.textContent = "Input too long";    
}
```

Why can't I just declare a variable `field_error` with `.textContent`, as I did with `field` and `.value.trim()`, instead using `.textContent` later?

Comment: What type is field_error? a DIV or SPAN or INPUT...?

Comment: Because [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) evaluates to a `string` which in turn is **primitive**. So when you assigned `field_error` its a copy (passed by value) and not a reference. Changing that would only affect itself and not the DOM.

Comment: Type is `<small>`. I understand what I was doing wrong, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property actually operates more like a getter/setter, potentially applying a transform on get (eg concatenation of the textContent of every child node).

In your first case `field_error` is pointing at the result of that get (which is now unrelated to the `#field_error` element) so making changes won't effect the original object.

Your `field` value likewise couldn't be set (to update the `#field` element) because it's a manipulated copy of the value.. not a pointer to the DOM element.

Comment: Oh, so im actually giving variable `field_error` value of that element and not a pointer to the DOM element. Thanks, I understand now.